# Name of the instance doesn't appear on the result

Tags: java

```java
public class Droid{
    String name; 
    int batterylevel;

    public String toString(){
        return "Hello , I'm the droid :" + name +" "+ batterylevel+"%";
    }

    public Droid(String droidname){
        droidname=name;
        batterylevel=100;
    }

    public void performtask(String task){
        System.out.println(name+"is performing task "+task);
        batterylevel=10;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Droid codey= new Droid("codey");
        System.out.println(codey);
        codey.performtask("cooking..");
        codey.performtask("walking..");

        Droid codey2= new Droid("codey2");
        codey2.performtask("drawing..");
    }
}
```

Here is the code for a  droid performing some tasks and it should show its name and its  performing task .

The problem is its not printing name it shows null instead .

I'm the droid :null 100%

**nullis** performing task cooking..

**nullis** performing task walking..

**null** is performing task drawing..

I expect that Null should be replaced by its name .

I'm the droid :null 100%

***codey*** performing task cooking..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/c5ddc50bc6006023feac21c3227ca8ed

Comment: Need a much better explanation before anyone could begin to help on this. Add the code to the question and nicely format the actual output along with the expected so everyone can clearly see what you want.

Comment: I had posted the code too I don't know why it doesn't show it here . but here is the link for the code https://gist.github.com/c5ddc50bc6006023feac21c3227ca8ed

Comment: Please take the [tour], read the [ask] guide and then [edit] your question accordingly. There is absolutely no way anyone could answer your current "question."

Comment: I can't post the next questions since I got  thumb down for my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are not actually assigning the name field.

You need to reverse the line:

```java
droidname=name;
```

To be instead:

```java
name=droidname;
```

Comment: Trey Graham Thank you so much .It worked.